# Update Filename Before Extension In Database

Tags: mysql, sql

When an action is performed on our CRM it triggers a process.  What I am wanting is that when it meets certain criteria I need to update the name of the document in the database.  However, if the document is called, for example:

```
Prospectus.docx
```

I want to rename the document: Prospectus_1.docx

How do I do an update to add a number before the document extension?

```
$sql = "UPDATE b_bp_history SET NAME ='$documentName_[this is where I need the number before the document extension] ' 
WHERE ID='".$_POST['ID']."
```

I am thinking that I need to maybe strip the document extension first and then add it on after?

I have the orginal document name stored as $documentName.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: From where you call that update statment?? , I mean you can do separate process for generate file name and send it as variable to update statements simply.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to generate the new document name (`$newDocumentName`), given `$documentName` and `$number` using PHP's [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) function:

```
$newDocumentName = preg_replace('/(.*)\.(.*)/', '$1_' . $number . '.$2', $documentName);
```

Then use `$newDocumentName` in the `SET` clause of your `UPDATE` SQL statement like so:

```
$sql = "UPDATE b_bp_history SET NAME ='$newDocumentName' WHERE ID='".$_POST['ID']."
```